# Concat a string to a field value into a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add a string i.e "Building " to each random name of my table.

I tried concat, & and +

```
UPDATE officine 
       SET nom = (SELECT fake_name.last_name
                               FROM fake_name
                               ORDER BY rand()
                               LIMIT 1);
```

I have actually :

```
Dupont
March
```

and I would like to get

```
Building Dupont
Building March
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
UPDATE officine 
       SET nom = (SELECT CONCAT('Building ', fake_name.last_name)
                  FROM fake_name
                  ORDER BY rand()
                  LIMIT 1
                 );
```